# WordPress URL Rewrite - Optional Value

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the following URL in WP:
http://www.example.com/?compra=arriendo&propertytype=apartamentos&location=bogota&habitaciones=2-habitaciones

to:
http://www.viveya.co/arriendo/apartamentos/bogota/2-habitaciones

This is my code:

> function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
>       global $wp_rewrite;
>
> ```
> $new_rules = array(
>     '(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.*)/?$' => 'index.php?compra=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&propertytype=' .
> ```
>
> $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&location=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3)
>   . '&habitaciones=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4)
>       );
>       $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
>
> }
>
> add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );

Now, I want habitaciones to be optional. So if I enter the following URL:
http://www.viveya.co/arriendo/apartamentos/bogota/

It will still work. (the original URL will be &habitaciones=).

My code doesn't work when habitaciones is empty. I have no idea why. What's wrong with my regex?

Thanks in advance!
Adam

Comment: Any particular reason why you didn't post this on [WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that can be solved with regular expressions.

You need to parse the URL segments using PHP. Untested proof of concept:

```
$segments = explode( '/', $url );

$query = array();

while ( $segments ) {
  $part = array_shift( $segments );

  if ( in_array( $part, array( 'taxonomy1', 'taxonomy2', ... ) ) {
    $query[ $part ] = array_shift( $segments );
  }
}
```

Edit: Well, I suppose you could also use regex, but you'll need an additional rewrite rule for each optional value:

```
function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array(
        'event/(industry|location)/(.+)/(industry|location)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=eg_event&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'event/(industry|location)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=eg_event&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

Source: http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

Comment: Thank you very much, added additional rewrite rule for each optional value!!:)